# Given N points in a 2D plane, determine if there is a line that divides them into two sets of N / 2 points each + some more rules

Tags: algorithm, line, computer-science, computational-geometry, point

Given N points on a 2D plane, determine if there is a line that divides them into two sets of N / 2 points each.

There are two more rules:

- The sum of the distances of each set of points to this line should be the same.
- The line can't pass through any of the points.

Extras (not sure if helps):
We can assume that `N` is large (~100k); -2000 <= x[i], y[i] <= 2000

Do you folks have any insights to this problem ? I really tried many stuff but I believe that I should use some sort of equality, or prove something like: sum(distancesSet1[i]) = sum(distancesSet2[i]).
If you want, I can also post here the stuff that I tried and failed (or I think it failed), but before I'd like to see your suggestions.

Thank you so much!

**#Edit:**
**What I need to know for this problem is to exactly say whether it's possible or not given the set of N points.**

Comment: After seeing your edit I'd change the title of the question to something along these lines: "Given N points in a 2D plane, determine if there is a line that divides them (...)"

Comment: I am not really used to stack overflow, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: No worries, but you took it too literally! I wrote "(...)" to represent the rest of the question. It's probably a good idea to complete the title again.

Comment: I am not sure if this is ok to do but I'd like to raise this question again.
Does anyone have any hint or anything you know that is related to solve this question ?

Comment: Here's an idea: 1) pick an axis, e.g. x; 2) find the median and average; 3) if there's no points between the median and the average, then there's a line perpendicular to that axis that crosses the average and that divides the points; 4) else, try the same with the other axis. If both fail, it's possible that the line still exists, but I don't know how to prove either way. Hope this helps as a start.

Comment: This is actually what I've been trying to do, I am almost convinced that this line has to pass through the average point. Having a point that I am assuming that would need to be on this line makes things easier but still not many ideas on how to actually solve it :(
I think that the idea is to find a decent algorithm to rotate the points (and test whenever the points would lie on side A or B of this line) around this center point or something like this :(

Comment: I really can't develop more from this idea, I am not sure if my skills with geometry are not enough or if there's something important missing to solve this problem.

Comment: @dalmo, I've actually figured out how to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

*Update: This was an attempt to answer the initial, more general question of whether it was possible to divide the points or not.*

The problem as defined by your constraints is mathematically unsolvable. You can't guarantee that the sums of the distances will be equal for both sets.

All you need as proof is a counterexample:

```
S = [[-1000,0], [0,0], [1,0], [2,0]]
```

There is only one possible combination to separate the pairs:

```
S1 = [[-1000,0], [0,0]] 
S2 = [[1,0], [2,0]]
```

All points are on a line `L1`. Given your bullet #2 we can conclude that any line `L2` that separate those points will form an angle `t` wrt `L1`. The sum of the distances are then:

```
sum1 = a*sin(t)   ::   1000 < a < 1002  
sum2 = b*sin(t)   ::      1 < b < 3

   t != 0
sum1 > sum2

QED
```

Comment: How would you write the algorithm to say if it's possible or not ? I mean, the line itself I don't need to know, just if it is possible to have this line.